# How to auto-create mount points in /Volume with sshfs

Tags: finder, ssh, filesystem, mount, disk-volume

I believe the title says it all, but anyways:
I would like to recreate the OSX behaviour of auto-creating mount points in /Volumes with sshfs mounting remote folders and auto-deleting these mount points. I prefer this to have mount target folders hanging around with no other sense then waiting to get something mounted on it. ;)
Is there a way to achieve this with sshfs?

Comment: Let's use the ssh tag for now - search does a great job of letting us find sshfs and we are working to keep tags broad enough for people to want to follow them.

Comment: Did you record any progress on that? It looks like one should use the latest [FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.io/), setup key authentication and then add a line to `/etc/fstab`, however I keep getting Permission denied errors from the server, it looks like the key is ignored (although I can `ssh` with the key).

Answer (score 1):

The [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org) Menuling will do that for you if you're willing to use a GUI. The menuling is a little crashy on Mountain Lion, but you may be able to fix that since the source is on Github.

Comment: tried it, and don't have time to fix it. ;) It really disconnects by crash every 3 minutes.